# Get input data from fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am having a main activity which includes a `view pager` with different `fragments`. Each fragment inherits some input fields as `EditTexts`. Now I am asking how to collect all these data from the main activity.

Comment: share what you tried and please be clear with the question

Answer (score 0):

Write method in activity

```
public String getData() {
        return editText.getText().toString();
    }
```

And call it from fragment

```
 String data = ((YourActivity) context).getData();
```

Comment: You are transfering in the wrong direction.The data needs to be transfered from multiple fragments to one main activity

Answer (score 0):

1) In your fragment create an interface (let's call it ActivityMessenger) with method updateFragmentText(String string);

2) You have to make also a variable ActivityMessenger mActivityMessenger; and override onAttach(Context context) method.

So the Fragment code snippet should like this:

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment {
  //... field declarations here
  ActivityMessenger mActivityMessenger;

  // ... constructor and other stuff

  public interface ActivityMessenger {
    updateFragmentText(String text);
  }

  // ... on mButton click event we send this String to Activity:
  mButton.setOnClickListener(v->mActivityMessenger.updateFragmentText(message));

  @Override
  onAttach(Context context){
    // here we attach the parent Activity as an ActivityMessenger
    mActivityMessenger = (ActivityMessenger)context;
  }
}
```

In your Main Activity:

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ActivityMessenger {
// ... field declarations
private String mStringFromFragment;
// ... other stuff, init Fragment etc.

  @Override
  updateFragmentText(String text){
    mStringFromFragment = text;
  }
}
```

That's it. Hope I could help you!
Regards, Cs

Answer (score 0):

You will need to provide more information on how you are designing your app. With `viewpager` in your activity, you will be able to collect data from only the active fragment, the one on display.

You can have all your editTexts on one fragment and collect information and pass it to another activity via intent.

EDIT:- Code Reference

```
    public class SampleFragment extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(..){
    ....
    }
     public void onButtonClicked(View view){

     //collect data from your edit texts
     string text = editText.getText().to String();
     string text2 = editText2.getText().toString();
     ....
      ..
    //send data via intent
    Intent anotherActivity = new Intent(this, anotherActivity.class);
    anotherActivity.putExtra("Text1", text);
    anotherActivity.putExtra("Text2", text2);
    .......
    startActivity(anotherActivity);
   }
```

Check this [link](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide) for a detailed description on using viewpager

Answer (score 0):

In your activity define global string variable which holds your fragment value:

```
String firstFragmentEdittext;
String secondFragmentEdittext;
String thirdFragmentEdittext;
```

and define method which access by every fragment:

```
public void setValue(String editTextValue, int fragmentIndex)
    {
        switch(fragmentIndex)
        {
            case 1:
            {
                firstFragmentEdittext = editTextValue;
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                secondFragmentEdittext= editTextValue;
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                thirdFragmentEdittext= editTextValue;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

How to send from fragment to activity: For Fragment 1

```
((YourActivity) getActivity()).setValue(edittext.getText().toString(), 1);
```